# Python Programming error 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def censor(text, word):
    my_text_list = text.split()
    a =" "
    b = 0
    for a in word:
        a = a + "*"
    for word in my_text_list:
        b = my_text_list.index(word)
        my_text_list[b] = a
    text = " ".join(my_text_list)
    return text
print censor("abcde","a")
```

It returns an error telling that it cannot replace the string properly.

Kindly help me out . Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you still getting error after fixing indentation or not ?

Comment: or what output you want ?

Comment: actually i want the output without the word a in it. Its not replacing the a with * . Where word is found in the text it should be replaced with an *

Comment: can you put input and expected output so, every one clear with your question.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly this after fixing the indentation:

```
  def censor(text,word):
        my_text_list = text.split()
        a =" "
        b = 0
        for a in word:
            a = a + "*"
            for word in my_text_list:
                b = my_text_list.index(word)
                my_text_list[b] = a
                text = " ".join(my_text_list)

        return text

print censor("abcde","a")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
def censor(text, word):
    return text.replace(word, '*')
print censor("abcde","a")
```

Output:

```
*bcde
```

Or without using replace:

```
def censor(text, word):
    return ''.join([[e, '*'][e == word] for e in text ])
print censor("abcdea","a")
```

Output:

```
*bcde*
```